# Why creating SKLabelNode in Sprite-kit results in "Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value"

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I am trying to create a score label with an `SKLabelNode` in SpriteKit and it results in the project crashing with this error:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value

I've tried many alternate ways and it results in the same error. This is the basic version of the code.

```
class LevelScene: SKScene {

    // Coin Label + Constants
    var coinLabel: SKLabelNode!

    var currentCoins = 0 {
        didSet {
            coinLabel.text = ":\(currentCoins)"
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Coin Label
        coinLabel.text = ":0"
        coinLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(coinLabel)
    }
}
```

Comment: You never actually instantiate `coinLabel` Try `var coinLabel = SKLabelNode()`

Comment: You don't ***create*** the node, you only declared it.

Comment: Thanks you that was the issue! I needed to set it up as var coinLabel = SKLabelNode()

Answer (score -1):

try first create a object of SKLabelNode like this

```
class LevelScene: SKScene {

    // Coin Label + Constants
    var coinLabel: SKLabelNode!

    var currentCoins = 0 {
        didSet {
            coinLabel.text = ":\(currentCoins)"
        }
    }

    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
        // Coin Label
        coinLabel = SKLabelNode() // Here you initialize the SKLabelNode
        coinLabel.text = ":0"
        coinLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        addChild(coinLabel)
    }
}
```

This erro occurs because you try access the label before initialize.

Hope this help.